# SQL Sylob return a boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

I am currently discovering the Sylob 5 ERP and I would like some help on one of my queries because the Sylob support is overwhelmed with demands.
I would like my query to display if one of the operations in my fabrication order is late.
I already have a query that displays every operations and if it's late or not:

```
SELECT
  distinct
  ordreFabrication.codeOF as Code_OF,
  operationOrdreFabrication.libelle as Libelle,
  operationOrdreFabrication.centreCharge.libelle || ' (' ||             
  operationOrdreFabrication.centreCharge.code || ')' as Centre_charge,
  operationOrdreFabrication.dateDebutPrevue as Début_prévu,
  (
  CASE 
    WHEN current_date() > operationOrdreFabrication.dateDebutPrevue and 
    operationOrdreFabrication.etatAvancementOperationOF = '0'  THEN ('<div style=''color:red''>' || 
    'Retard sur le début' || ' </div>') 
    WHEN current_date() > operationOrdreFabrication.dateFinPrevue and 
    operationOrdreFabrication.etatAvancementOperationOF != '2' THEN ('<div style=''color:red''>' || 
    'Retard sur la fin' || ' </div>')
    ELSE ('Aucun retard') 
  END
  ) as Retard,
operationOrdreFabrication.dateDebutReelle as Début_Réel,
operationOrdreFabrication.dateFinPrevue as Fin_prévue
FROM
  OperationOrdreFabricationEntite as operationOrdreFabrication
  left outer join operationOrdreFabrication.ordreFabrication as ordreFabrication
  WHERE
    operationOrdreFabrication.id not like 'DefaultRecord_%'
  AND
    operationOrdreFabrication.dateFinValidite is null
  AND
    ordreFabrication.dateFinValidite is null
  AND
    operationOrdreFabrication.sousTraitance in ('false')
  AND
    ((current_date() > operationOrdreFabrication.dateDebutPrevue and             
    operationOrdreFabrication.etatAvancementOperationOF = '0'
    ) OR (current_date() > operationOrdreFabrication.dateFinPrevue and 
    operationOrdreFabrication.etatAvancementOperationOF != '2'))
  ORDER BY
    1 asc
```

But I want this to return true or false when my case returns anything else than "Aucun retard"
so I can use it as a subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want EXISTS  (NOT EXISTS)

```
select exists(
  select 1 
  from (
    --you original query
  ) t
  where retard = 'Aucun retard') flag
```